# When I edit my R snippets in the Tools tab, why are they not available in the console?

Tags: r, session, rstudio, code-snippets, devtools

**Question:**

I have navigated to *Tools>Global Options...>Code --> Edit Snippets...* and can see the available snippets that I should have access to, edit the file to add more of my own. I have added a snippet

```
snippet tryCatch
    ${1:variable} <- tryCatch({
        ${2}
    }, warning = function(w) {
        message(sprintf("Warning in %s: %s", deparse(w[["call"]]), w[["message"]]))
        ${3}
    }, error = function(e) {
        message(sprintf("Error in %s: %s", deparse(e[["call"]]), e[["message"]]))
        ${4}
    }, finally = {
        ${5}
    })
```

but it fails to be recognized in my `interactive()` R session. How do I add a snippet, any ideas why editing isn't working?

**Background:**

I have recently been introduced to R `snippets`, pre-written sections of code to retrieve with a string while on the R console. I have seen multiple people on YouTube do this with no issue. I am trying to edit the file to customize my own snippets to speed the writing process up of commonly used calls to `assert::assert()` and `tryCatch()`. I have looked at the file location of the snippets to see the content in `~\AppData\Roaming\RStudio\snippets\r.snippets`. I have edited the file in both places and resarted the IDE and my R session to no avail and the only snippets I can access are the one preloaded from `shinysnippets`.

- `r.snippets` file;

```
snippet module
    ${1:name}ui <- function(id){
        ns <- NS(id)
        tagList(
        ${0}
            )
        }

    ${1:name} <- function(input, output, session){
        ns <- session\$ns
    }
    
    # Copy in UI
    #${1:name}ui("${1:name}ui")
    
    # Copy in server
    #callModule(${1:name}, "${1:name}ui")
    
snippet observe_event
    observeEvent( ${1:event} , {
    ${0}
    })
    
snippet with_progress
    withProgress( message = "${1:message}" , {
    ${0}
    })

snippet aa
    ${1:dataset} <- ${1:dataset} %>% ${0}

snippet sidebar_page
    library(shiny)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel( "${1:title}" ), 
      
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        
        ),
        mainPanel(
        
        )
      )
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)

snippet tryCatch
    ${1:variable} <- tryCatch({
        ${2}
    }, warning = function(w) {
        message(sprintf("Warning in %s: %s", deparse(w[["call"]]), w[["message"]]))
        ${3}
    }, error = function(e) {
        message(sprintf("Error in %s: %s", deparse(e[["call"]]), e[["message"]]))
        ${4}
    }, finally = {
        ${5}
    })   

snippet checkData
checkmate::checkDate(
                from,
                upper = today(),
                len = 1
)

snippet assert
assert::assert(
            ${1},
            msg = "\n\033[31mx\033[39m Error:\n ${2}"
        )
```

When typing `observe_event` into the cmd-line, you are greeted with a choice to input the above chunk of code, with the cursor automatically switching between the `$` anchors.

**Session Info**

```
devtools::sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] assert_1.0.1               rameritrade_0.1.5          httr_1.4.2                
 [4] quantmod_0.4.18            RVerbalExpressions_0.1.0   PerformanceAnalytics_2.0.4
 [7] tbl2xts_1.0.4              bizdays_1.0.9              tictoc_1.0.1              
[10] glue_1.6.1                 here_1.0.1                 polite_0.1.1              
[13] rvest_1.0.2                Riex_1.0.2                 TTR_0.24.3                
[16] xts_0.12.1                 zoo_1.8-9                  lubridate_1.8.0           
[19] forcats_0.5.1              stringr_1.4.0              dplyr_1.0.8               
[22] purrr_0.3.4                readr_2.1.2                tidyr_1.2.0               
[25] ggplot2_3.3.5              tidyverse_1.3.1            plyr_1.8.6                
[28] furrr_0.2.3                future_1.24.0              tidyjson_0.3.1            
[31] reshape2_1.4.4             ProjectTemplate_0.10.2     tibble_3.1.6              
[34] digest_0.6.29             

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] utf8_1.2.2               tidyselect_1.1.2         lme4_1.1-28             
  [4] grid_4.1.0               robotstxt_0.7.13         munsell_0.5.0           
  [7] codetools_0.2-18         effectsize_0.6.0.1       miniUI_0.1.1.1          
 [10] withr_2.5.0              colorspace_2.0-3         config_0.3.1            
 [13] knitr_1.37               rstudioapi_0.13          listenv_0.8.0           
 [16] emmeans_1.7.2            httr2_0.1.1              urltools_1.7.3          
 [19] roll_1.1.6               polyclip_1.10-0          farver_2.1.0            
 [22] datawizard_0.3.0         rprojroot_2.0.2          parallelly_1.30.0       
 [25] vctrs_0.3.8              generics_0.1.2           xfun_0.30               
 [28] ipred_0.9-12             R6_2.5.1                 shinysnippets_0.0.0.9000
 [31] cachem_1.0.6             assertthat_0.2.1         promises_1.2.0.1        
 [34] scales_1.1.1             nnet_7.3-16              ggExtra_0.9             
 [37] gtable_0.3.0             miceadds_3.11-6          globals_0.14.0          
 [40] timeDate_3043.102        rlang_1.0.1              berryFunctions_1.21.0   
 [43] splines_4.1.0            lazyeval_0.2.2           keyring_1.3.0           
 [46] broom_0.7.12             checkmate_2.0.0          yaml_2.2.1              
 [49] abind_1.4-5              modelr_0.1.8             backports_1.4.1         
 [52] httpuv_1.6.5             tools_4.1.0              lava_1.6.10             
 [55] usethis_2.1.5            ellipsis_0.3.2           tsibble_1.1.1           
 [58] Rcpp_1.0.8               timetk_2.7.0             rpart_4.1-15            
 [61] slider_0.2.2             haven_2.4.3              fs_1.5.2                
 [64] magrittr_2.0.2           data.table_1.14.2        brochure_0.0.0.9023     
 [67] warp_0.2.0               triebeard_0.3.0          reprex_2.0.1            
 [70] mvtnorm_1.1-3            sjmisc_2.8.9             pkgload_1.2.4           
 [73] hms_1.1.1                mime_0.12                xtable_1.8-4            
 [76] XML_3.99-0.9             sjstats_0.18.1           readxl_1.3.1            
 [79] testthat_3.0.4           compiler_4.1.0           mice_3.14.0             
 [82] crayon_1.5.0             minqa_1.2.4              htmltools_0.5.2         
 [85] later_1.3.0              tzdb_0.2.0               RcppParallel_5.1.5      
 [88] DBI_1.1.2                tweenr_1.0.2             sjlabelled_1.1.8        
 [91] dbplyr_2.1.1             MASS_7.3-54              rappdirs_0.3.3          
 [94] boot_1.3-28              Matrix_1.3-3             cli_3.2.0               
 [97] mitools_2.4              runner_0.4.1             quadprog_1.5-8          
[100] parallel_4.1.0           insight_0.16.0           gower_1.0.0             
[103] golem_0.3.2              pkgconfig_2.0.3          microbenchmark_1.4.9    
[106] recipes_0.2.0            roxygen2_7.1.2           xml2_1.3.3              
[109] hardhat_0.2.0            estimability_1.3         prodlim_2019.11.13      
[112] anytime_0.3.9            attempt_0.3.1            parameters_0.16.0       
[115] tidyquant_1.0.3          RQuantLib_0.4.15         cellranger_1.1.0        
[118] curl_4.3.1               shiny_1.7.1              gtools_3.9.2            
[121] rjson_0.2.21             nloptr_2.0.0             bench_1.1.2             
[124] lifecycle_1.0.1          nlme_3.1-152             jsonlite_1.7.3          
[127] desc_1.4.1               fansi_1.0.2              pillar_1.7.0            
[130] lattice_0.20-44          fastmap_1.1.0            survival_3.2-11         
[133] ratelimitr_0.4.1         bayestestR_0.11.5        ggforce_0.3.3           
[136] class_7.3-19             stringi_1.6.2            performance_0.8.0       
[139] Quandl_2.11.0            rsample_0.1.1            memoise_2.0.1           
[142] future.apply_1.8.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R Snippets are notorious for being sensitive to spaces vs tabs as @DonaldSeinen has pointed out. You need to ensure that there are no red spaces in the text fields when editing your R snippet, this will render the snippet useless.

**TIP**

when writing snippet code, please use `tab` in order to remedy this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet file is sensitive to spaces, use tabs instead.

[image]

The first snippet should work correctly. The second one will show up in autocompletion but won't do anything.

New snippets are recognized by RStudio on saving the snippets file, restarting RStudio is not needed. This can also be done programmatically if you want the `tryCatch` snippet to be populated with specific content for different use cases.